# Ajax Modal Popup

Tags: modalpopupextender

I am displaying data in a gridview. A link is bound in it.
On that linnk button event, a ajax modal popup is shown.
That modal popup contains a windows media player control and a repeater control.
Repeater contains the audio files, and when select 1 of them, that file will played in that player control.
The problem is that, when audio file is in play mode AND the modal popup is closed,
that audio file is remains in play mode untill any other server side event not occurs.
-How to stop that file when closing popup??
Plz help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how exactly did you get the modal popup to work on that link click?
I have a button in a gridview that I created programmatically and I can't seem to get a modal popup to work.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is for server requests not pop-up windows so i'm a little confused about what you are asking.

If you want to stop playback of the audio file once the pop-up window is closed you could try to use a `onclose` event handler to stop the playback. This would only work if javascipt can interact with the media player.